# Wordpress - Add "active" class if current page is active

Tags: php, css, wordpress

```
<?php
          if($post->post_parent)
          $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
          else
          $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
          if ($children) {
        $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);?>

        <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
          <?php echo $children; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

The code above lists the parent and all child pages in a list.

Parent Page
Child Page
Child Page class="active"
Child Page
Child Page

I would like to add a class of "active" to the currently active page. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

To look for a specific page and add an active class to it, you can try using is_page and define the URL/slug of the page.

```
<a  class="<?php if (is_page('name-of-page')) echo 'active'; ?>" href="#">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add active and other classes by checking the `$post->post_title` against the `$item->title`

```
function addLinkClassesWithActive( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    global $post;
    // check if the item is in the primary menu
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main-nav' ) {
        // add the desired attributes:
        $atts['class'] = $post->post_title === $item->title ? 'mdl-layout__tab is-active' : 'mdl-layout__tab';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'addLinkClassesWithActive', 10, 3 );
```

I am using this myself and stripping out the wrapping container, the ul, and the li tags so that I have just a link. See example below.

```
<nav role="navigation" class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <?php
        $primaryMenu = array(
            'container' => false,
            'theme_location' => 'main-nav',
            'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
            'echo' => false,
        );
        echo strip_tags( wp_nav_menu( $primaryMenu ), '<a>' );
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```